# Is it possible to change the querystring variable in ASP.NET MVC path before it hits the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, query-string, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller method in ASP.NET MVC that looks like this:

```
public ActionResult GetAlbumPictures(int albumId)
{
    var album = AlbumRepo.GetSingle(albumId);
    var pictures = album.Pictures;
    return View(pictures);
}
```

The routing for this method looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
                "pictures"
                new { controller = "Album", action = "GetAlbumPictures" });
```

The user will use the following URL to get the pictures, filtered by the album ID:

```
GET http://server/pictures?albumid=10
```

However, I'd like to change the querystring parameter to just `album` instead of `albumid`:

```
GET http://server/pictures?album=10
```

This would mean that the controller method needs to be modified to:

```
public ActionResult GetPictures(int album)
{
    ...
}
```

However, this is not ideal because now the method has a parameter named `album`, which can be confused as an `Album` **object** instead of the `ID` of the `Album`.

My question is, is there any way of configuring ASP.NET MVC so that in the routing, it will receive a querystring parameter called `album`, but then pass it off to the controller as the `albumId` parameter?

**P.S.** I know that I can do this in the routing table:

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
                "album/{albumId}/pictures",
                new { controller = "Album", action = "GetAlbumPictures" });
```

But due to legacy issues, I have to make it work for the querystring method as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a custom action filter attribute to handle this scenario. I haven't tested this specific implementation, but the general idea is to do something like this:

```
public class AlbumAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
         public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
         {
             var albumId = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["album"] as string;
             filterContext.ActionParameters["albumId"] = albumId;

             base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
         }
    }
```

Then, decorate your action method with the [Album] attribute:

```
[Album]
public ActionResult GetAlbumPictures(int albumId)
{
    var album = AlbumRepo.GetSingle(albumId);
    var pictures = album.Pictures;
    return View(pictures);
}
```

Comment: It will not work, as Request.QueryString["album"] is not accessible within AlbumAttribute class.

Comment: Actually, yes it is. I've updated the code to reflect the correct way of accessing it.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the most elegant solution.

Comment: I need to change the value of querystring before passing to all the actions. Where should I do it instead of adding an action filter attribute to each action?

Comment: @Leon: you can change it in Controller OnActionExecuting(). Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/uYCmfvXr

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Custom Model Binder and it will work with both album and albumId.
It can be implemented as follows:

**Custom Model Binder:**

```
public class AlbumModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel
    (ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        int albumId;
        var albumVar = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue( "album" );
        if (albumVar != null)
        {
            albumId = int.Parse( albumVar.AttemptedValue );
        }
        else
        {
            albumId = int.Parse( bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue( "albumId" ).AttemptedValue );
        }
        return albumId;
    }
}
```

**Action implementation:**

```
public ActionResult GetAlbumPictures
([ModelBinder( typeof( AlbumModelBinder ) )] int albumId)
{
    var album = AlbumRepo.GetSingle(albumId);
    var pictures = album.Pictures;
    return View(pictures);
}
```

**Global.asax.cs implementation:**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add( typeof( int ), new AlbumModelBinder() );
    RegisterRoutes( RouteTable.Routes );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A custom model binder would work great, but for something trivial like this case, it's just a little more work than I'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Consider intercepting your request and use HttpContext.RewritePath to alter the query string before its picked up by the Routing engine. There is a nice diagram here showing how Url Rewriting is executed ages before the routing :)

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/

Answer (score -1):

You can intercept the request before it hits the controller in Application_BeginRequest in your global.asax. You won't have access to the MVC contexts though, but could use

```
Server.Transfer(...);
```

or

```
Response.Redirect(...); 
Response.End();
```

Comment: why wouldn't you use HttpContext.RewritePath in a case like this? IMO its perfect for these kind of cases, no?