# Sending An Object From Link To Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view that takes a Model of type

```
public class Product
{
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string LongDescription { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }

    public Product()
    {
        Documents = new List<Document>();
    }

}
```

When clicking the following link I want to invoke a controller and somehow pass the List as a parameter to the controller

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("Browse", "Home", new { docList= Model.Douments})" data-role="button" data-icon="search" class="my-btn">Available Documents</a>

   public ActionResult Browse(List<Documentr> docList)
        {}
```

If I dont have to pass the List on a querystring I dont want to.

Looking for help fixing my code to make this happen

Comment: Is your `Product` class an entity in a database?  Does it have an Id you can reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your over complicating this. I don't see why you would want to post *readonly* data to another controller action. Another issue with this approach is there is the potential for it to be out of date by the time the link is clicked (*slight* chance, but still possible). Also, if your initial view doesn't actually display any of the documents then I would strip that out of the model as it isn't required e.g.

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; } 
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; } 
    public string LongDescription { get; set; } 
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; } 
}

public ActionResult Product(int id)
{
    var model = new ProductViewModel();
    ... // populate view model
    return new View(model);
}
```

Then in your view, link to your product to browse

```
@Html.ActionLink("Browse Documents", "Home", "Documents", new { id = Model.Id })
```

Then have your `Documents` action pull the product again and this time send down the documents

```
public ActionResult Browse(int productId)
{
    var product = ... // get product by id
    return View(product.Documents);
}
```

General rule of thumb - **only give the view what it needs**

Comment: how do I get the product by Id from the viewModel can you show me that code?

Comment: Also after all this is it the same performance wise if I simply query the enitity model again and get the documents for the part from the database again?

Comment: @NickLaMarca `how do I get the product by id` - how can I tell you how to do this if I don't know what sort of ORM you are using? `is the performance the same` - depending on how much data you need to retrieve (and how optimized your database is) you will probably notice a longer delay, however, storing large amounts of data in the page (like you were trying to do) can lead to page load delays anyway so the difference is probably negligiable. Also if your worried about page load time look at paging/ajax instead of pulling all the data down in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a ViewModel to pass the data (easiest way).

Or, you could do it the hard way using a custom action filter or a custom model binder [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4842923/1026898).

The reason why the method you are attempting does not work is that the passing a List as a parameter does not get handled by MVC properly through the default model binder.

---

**Update**

Since seeing you update your post with the list being part of a bigger Product class, I wonder why you don't just reference the product at your destination action by id?  (I don't know what the name of your entity Key is, but I'm going to assume it is "`Id`"

Your link would change to something like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("DocumentList", "Home", new { id = Model.Id})" data-role="button" data-icon="search" class="my-btn">Available Documents</a>
```

And you would have your Action:

```
public ActionResult DocumentList ( int id )
{
    var product = db.Product.Find(Id);
    return View(product.List)
}
```

Comment: yes, a case where a viewModel is passing a complex object from a view to a controller

Comment: what is "db" in your code? I have this but there isnt a Find method in it  private ContentEntities context = new ContentEntities();

Comment: I wrote this under the assumption that your Product objects are entities within a database.  `db` would be your database context.

Comment: No I created an object product and did a LINQ join to populate the Product object from the data in the database

Comment: @miscusermandude LINQ doesn't auto-generate an Id for you, the database does (and only if you have configured it to do so). LINQ stands for "Language Integrated Query" and is a *querying* language.